# How I can override this Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs.php

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3

How I can override the breadcrumb.php file .as If I am using in `app/design/frontend/Oc/jb/Magento_Catalog/Block/Breadcrumb.php` its giving error.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Catalog breadcrumbs
 */
namespace Oc\Jb\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class MyBreadcrumbs extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        Data $catalogData
        Context $context;
        $data = array();
        parent::__construct($context,$catalogData, $data);
    }


    public function getTitleSeparator($store = null)
    {
        $separator = (string)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue('catalog/seo/title_separator', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store);
        return ' ' . $separator . ' ';
    }
    public function getCategory ($product) {   
        $_categoryFactory = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
        // for multiple categories, select only the first one
        // remember, index = 0 is 'Default' category
        if (! $product->getCategoryIds())
            return null;
        if (isset ( $product->getCategoryIds()[1]))
            $categoryId = $product->getCategoryIds()[1] ;
        else
            $categoryId = $product->getCategoryIds()[0] ;
        // Additionally for other types of attributes (select, multiselect, ..)
        $category = $_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
       return ['label' => $category->getName(), 'url' => $category->getUrl() ] ;

    }
    /**
     * Preparing layout
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product'); 
        //return parent::_prepareLayout();
        if ($breadcrumbsBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')) {
            $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb(
                'home',
                [
                    'label' => __('Home'),
                    'title' => __('Go to Home Page'),
                    'link' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
                ]
            );
            $title = [];
            $path = $this->_catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();

            // If we are at the product page and the $path does not include a category, 
            // then we will append the category link  here manually
            // Magento doesn't seem to append category paths to breadcrums consistently
            // Reported here; https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7967
            if($product != null ) {
                // check for category path
                $foundCatPath=false;
                foreach ($path as $name => $breadcrumb) {
                    if ( strpos ( $name, 'category' ) > -1 )  
                        $foundCatPath=true;
                }
                // append the category path
                if (! $foundCatPath) {
                    $productCategory = $this->getCategory($product) ;
                    if ($productCategory) {
                        $categoryPath = [ 'category' => ['label' =>  $productCategory['label'] , 'link' =>  $productCategory['url']]  ];
                        $path = array_merge ($categoryPath ,$path );
                    } 
                }

            }
            foreach ($path as $name => $breadcrumb) {
                $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb($name, $breadcrumb);
                $title[] = $breadcrumb['label'];
            }
            // print_r ($path );
            // die ();
            $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(join($this->getTitleSeparator(), array_reverse($title)));
        }
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}






}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a plugin/interceptor, which is architecturally a more streamline solution than others posted. You can accomplish this with either the "before" or "around" methods. Each has it's benefits.

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Foo_Bar',
    __DIR__
);
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Foo_Bar" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs">
        <plugin name="foo_bar_plugin_breadcrumbs_modification" type="Foo\Bar\Plugin\BreadcrumbsPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

BreadcrumbsPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar\Plugin;

use \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs;

class BreadcrumbsPlugin
{
    // This is probably the "correct" way to account for this scenario
    public function beforeAddCrumb(Breadcrumbs $breadcrumbs, $crumbName, $crumbInfo)
    {
        if (isset($crumbInfo['label'])) {
            // This is where you can modify the breadcrumb text
            $crumbInfo['label'] = __($crumbInfo['label'] . ' baz');
        }

        return [
            $crumbName,
            $crumbInfo,
        ];
    }

    // Alternatively, you can use the "around" method
    public function aroundAddCrumb(Breadcrumbs $breadcrumbs, callable $proceed, $crumbName, $crumbInfo)
    {
        if (isset($crumbInfo['label'])) {
            // This is where you can modify the breadcrumb text
            $crumbInfo['label'] = __($crumbInfo['label'] . ' baz');
        }

        $proceed($crumbName, $crumbInfo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must create a module first.

**1. Module creation.**
Create file `app/code/Oc/Jb/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Oc_Jb" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

and `app/code/Oc/Jb/registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Oc_Jb',
    __DIR__
);
```

**2. Overriding Block**
Create file `app/code/Oc/Jb/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs.php
" type="Oc\Jb\Block\MyBreadcrumbs.php" />
</config>
```

Create your block file `Oc/Jb/Block/MyBreadcrumbs.php`.
**During overriding you must take care of what the parent class's constructor needs.** In your case for `Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs`, you will have to provide **`Context $context, Data $catalogData, array $data = []`**. For reference check core file.

```
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Catalog breadcrumbs
 */
namespace Oc\Jb\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class MyBreadcrumbs extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        Data $catalogData
        Context $context;
        $data = array();
        parent::__construct($context,$catalogData, $data);
    }
    //make necessary changes here.
}
```

**3. Run following commands:**

```
php bin/magento module:enable Oc_Jb
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I need to write all code in  __constuct () ?   As I want to update that code   https://gist.github.com/mbahar/82703c4b95d924d9bc8e6990202fdeba

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: all step successfully done but still vendor is calling

Comment: I updated breadcrumb.php code which I am using now

Comment: tere is another way as well. I will post it tomorrow. I'm sleeping now.

Comment: sure. thank you I updated  Breadcrumb code .

Comment: Try removing constructor function.

Comment: "Invalid application config. Unknown node: preference."

Answer (score 1):

You can't override php classes using theme. Just [create magento module](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/)  and override class using preferences :
[tutorial is here](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/)

Comment: I want this file to replace   breadcrumbs.php   https://gist.github.com/mbahar/82703c4b95d924d9bc8e6990202fdeba

Comment: Breadcrumbs.php is php class you cant override it like phtml files. Follow my instruction and you'll get success.

Comment: I am confuse in steps . Like  what will be my                 
        namespace Inchoo\Helloworld\Controller\Index;
 
 And what will that path mean ?    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;   . Can you share some steps if possible ?

Comment: First read this article http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/

Comment: @Learner namespace is the same as theme namespace in your case Oc/Jb or another you want. Mostly used vendorname/modulepurpose. For example Google/ReCaptcha. Then create folders like Oc/Jb/Block/Catalog/Block/Breadcrumbs.php and di.xml like in tutorial in second link