# Editing breadcrumbs ViewModel method

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, breadcrumbs, viewmodel

I am trying to override a method from **/vendor/magento/module-catalog/ViewModel/Product/Breadcrumbs.php**
I get an error Type Error occurred when creating object: Piranha\TagRemover\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs

My Module includes:

**etc/di.xml**

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs" 
                type="Piranha\TagRemover\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs" />
</config>
```

**ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Piranha\TagRemover\ViewModel\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;

/**
 * Product breadcrumbs view model.
 */
class Breadcrumbs extends \Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs implements ArgumentInterface
{
    /**
     * Catalog data.
     *
     * @var Data
     */
    private $catalogData;

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var Escaper
     */
    private $escaper;

    /**
     * @param Data $catalogData
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param Json|null $json
     * @param Escaper|null $escaper
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function __construct(
        Data $catalogData,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        Json $json = null,
        Escaper $escaper = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->catalogData = $catalogData;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->escaper = $escaper ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Escaper::class);
    }

    /**
     * Returns breadcrumb json with html escaped names
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getJsonConfigurationHtmlEscaped() : string
    {
        return json_encode(
            [
                'breadcrumbs' => [
                    'categoryUrlSuffix' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml($this->getCategoryUrlSuffix()),
                    'useCategoryPathInUrl' => (int)$this->isCategoryUsedInProductUrl(),
                    'product' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml($this->getProductName())
                ]
            ],
            JSON_HEX_TAG
        );
    }
}
```

Breadcrumbs.php contains the method I want to change but after running bin/magento setup:di:compile and including

```xml
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Catalog::product/breadcrumbs.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Piranha\TagRemover\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

to the catalog_product_view.xml I get the error when loading a product page.

Comment: i hope this helps you (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208130/how-i-can-override-this-magento-catalog-block-breadcrumbs-php)

Comment: @RobinioTor Thanks. I have looked at this, however, this is for Magento 2.1. The ViewModel was added in 2.2+

Comment: For what purpose did you overide the breadcrumb ? Is it because category path not showing in product detail page breadcrumb ?